# How to test all the JavaScript menu links in WatiN?

Tags: asp.net, watin

I am new to WatiN testing framework. I have a problem in testing a site page with JavaScript menu drop down links.

I have no idea how to deal with this task.....
I have to process all the links and go in to each page and perform further tests.

---

I hope you have misunderstood my question consider an example in this site
http://www.andrewsellick.com/examples/sliding-side-bar/#
My test sites include all kinds of  javascript menus, so my main idea is to execute javascript  and i think watin is the best way to do, unless using rhino library which has minimal usage.....

I have to find out the links and by using watin framework as i have to test tens of sites and i have to automate the process of extracting those links automatically and atleast should be able to open all those links

Any how thanks for ur reply. but it did not solve my problem......

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking forward to implement a navigation mechanism or do you intend to implement an automated links checker that will verify if each of the links is valid or not.

I would suggest that you implement a navigation mechanism first as part of the test framework and have your tests navigate the respective pages using this framework.

A good example is posted over here 
http://fmair.blogspot.com/2011/03/watin-on-crack.html

Or you could simply have one function that accepts a pipe separated string and identify the links on the ui and click on them to navigate further.

Regards,

Ashish Narmen

Answer (score 0):

**Specific answer:**

For the given example link here is code that will expand the sliding menu and flash / output the text of each link.

The sleep is there after the goto as it takes a bit for the menu to load.  I just picked 2500ms out of the air and it seemed to work each time.  Finding a better item to wait upon on would be a very good idea.

```
ie.GoTo("http://www.andrewsellick.com/examples/sliding-side-bar/#");

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
ie.Link("sideBarTab").Click();

foreach (ListItem currItem in ie.Div("sideBarContents").Lists[0].ListItems)
{
    currItem.Links[0].Flash(2);
    Console.WriteLine("link text: " + currItem.Links[0].Text);
}
```

Note: strictly speaking you don't even need to expand the slide menu as the links exist and are just hidden.  Expanding the menu is a good idea as it is what a user would do.

Used: IE8 and WatiN 2.1

**Generic answer**

To get each link on a given page, you'd iterate the *Links* collection

Example: (written from memory, not tested)

```
foreach (Link currLink in ie.Links)
{
     //do stuff
}
```

With this you'll run into problems of some links fire popups.  Some links expand menus.  Some links go to different pages.  Some links etc etc etc.  Also, you'd need to iterate each Frame as well as I believe those are seen as their own area and the above foreach wouldn't see any links in frames.

Coming up with a relatively generic solution is entirely possible IF your application(s) is written with good naming/CSS-classing/something so that you can know what a link is going to do based on its name/CSS-class/something.

Comment: I have given that site for only example, unless and untill u don,t know the specific elements this solutions will not work. I was thinking watin itself identifies and click on those menus......any how thanks for your code :)

Comment: your answer will work in cases where links are mentioned by href tags not in javascript menus, it is not possible to grab those dropdown menus using link collections...:(

Comment: Can you provide an "live" example of a menu you're referring to?  The javascript dropdown menus I deal with more often than not are just like the Sliding Side Bar link you posted -> the links exist, they're just hidden.

However, if it is being dynamically built due to a user behavior on the page (JQuery, some Tree implementations, etc) then you'll need to write code (objects hopefully) to deal with that situation as it is a specific case not a general case and any generic framework (WatiN, Selenium, etc) is not likely going to be a help for that specific case.